# difference between SConscript and SConstruct files?

Tags: python, scons

As a newbie to scons, I'm faced with converting a project with multiple modules in the one repo with a common top-level build.
Each module already has a SConstruct file - to allow building them on their own.

Reading on hierarchical scons setup, I see the idea is to use a top-level SConstruct which loads the sub-projects' build files using SConscript() function, and that those files are/should be called SConscript.
I find the rest of the info somewhat vague (or maybe TLDR?) - so

- wondering is that a requirement for those lower-level scripts to be
  SConscript files?
- IOW, is there a semantic/scope/evaluation
  difference between SConscripts and SConstructs apart from one
  intended as an entry point, whereas the other one just a "sub-build
  file"?
- Is there any point in refactoring those sub-project's SConstructs to
  be one liners to call a SConscript in the same level +
  chaining these up to the top level Sconstruct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your questions in order

1. No the lower level files can be called anything, as you specify the path and filename in the SConscript() call
2. Each SConscript is evaluated in it's own scope. You can pass via Export() (or SConscripts exports= argument) and bring into the SConscript (whatever you end up calling it) via Import().
3. Entirely depends if you want to do any central/top level configuration to be propagated to your sub projects.  This could still be done via Import() statements in the subproject's SConstruct and then checking if the variable you expect to have imported is defined (via try/except perhaps)

This sub project has SConstructs has been done before.  Likely it's cleaner to use Import() in your SConstructs in your sub project and then verify that whatever you expect to have passed is there or not before using it.  Wrapping that with copious comments as to why you are doing so if the sub projects are also used standalone..

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In Q1 I didn't mean filenames, I meant: can a SConstruct file can stand in there for SConscript() call -  or is there is some other difference between those and SConscript behaviour that I overlooked (eg the latter are never top-level). On Q3 - so if there are no common config (yet), they could just SConscript() all the sub-SConstructs  -and that would be equivalent of running scons in each sub dir? Thanks for the hits about Import() - something more to look up.

Comment: Q1: SConscripts are evaluated in almost identical environments as SConstruct's. So basically no difference.  Q3: some differences between running SConstruct in each directory.  "#" would reference the dir the SConstruct is in.  The sconsign file would by default be placed in the top level dir.  site_scons dir would be searched only in the top level dir (and not every subdir which could have their own site_scons dirs to service their SConstruct).  There may be some other differences, but those are the first ones which come to mind.  Basically I'd advise to just try it.

Comment: Also to bring such discussions to the SCons users mailing list where you'll get more ears from people who know about SCons..

Comment: Thanks for the tips - nearly forgot about signing up to their mailing list - since these days SO seems an easier solution to mostly everything else ;-) cheers for listing those differences, especially '#'.. I did try various things so far and one SConstruct was working standalone but not via loading into another one..probably to do with relative paths.

Comment: You could try passing the subdir name into the SConscript() via exports which the sub SConstructs could use and/or default to "."  If it's relative paths.

Comment: If my answer resolves your question(s), can you mark it as the answer?